# Accessing files in Jhipster (Angular + Springboot)

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jhipster

I have managed to develop a controller and service in the backend(spring) which successfully uploads a file on the server.

As far as upload location is concerned, I have used System.getProperty("user.dir") to get the path of the current project after which I have appended my custom folder structure specified in application.properties file. Moreover, I am saving the file path in database.

So, while trying to access the file from localmachine(localhost) on anchor tag, the file is successfully getting opened(downloaded to be precised).

However, when I push my application to the server, the project is added as a WAR java file. In the server, the file is getting uploaded to a folder which is outside my war file.

Hence I am not able to access the file from URL.

Please let me know if there is any way to fix this[image]. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure a path in your application.properties. In production, it would be absolute path and in dev a relative path. Alternatively, you could configure a url in yml using `file:`prefix for prod and `classpath:` prefix for dev to use `ResourceLoader`.